# Self-Hosted MongoDb Single Quotes Issue

Tags: php, mongodb, parse-platform

As Parse is getting closed we have migrated our apps data to self-hosted mongodb.

But we have encountered an issue with Single quotes .

**For example:**

**It's a new Day.**

When the database was hosted by parse itself we never had this issue and never needed extra code to escape the single quotes but now after migrating the parse and using self hosted mongodb we are facing this problem.

MongoDb data

```
{ "_id" : "vryoEYQqDt", "rowid" : 9, "image" : "982621c6338150d34c345ee62baa3420_outlet-335936476.jpg", "_created_at" : ISODate("2015-03-03T09:08:43.217Z"), "_updated_at" : ISODate("2016-11-09T08:20:21.074Z"), "name" : "Hello World" }
```

Parse code to insert in mongodb

```
$query = new ParseQuery("prodcuts");
        $query->equalTo("rowid", $rowid);

$object = $query->first();
$object->set("name", $pro_data->name);
try {
    $object->save();

    } catch (ParseException $ex) { 
      // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
      // error is a ParseException object with an error code and message.
      echo 'Failed to create new object, with error message: ' +    $ex->getMessage();
}
```

`"$pro_data->name"` - gets the name from MySql database. currently **"It's a new day"**.

When we execute this code . Mongo db updates the `"_updated_at" : ISODate("2016-11-09T08:20:21.074Z")` field but `"name" : "Hello World"` is not updated because it has a single quote which is not escaped.

Even Parse doesn't catch any exceptions.

Is there a way or config that escapes single quotes in MongoDb without using extra code in php?

Thanx in advance.

**Update:**

It might actually not be the single quotes which was not updating the mongo db but the UTF-8 characters.

Value of "$object" before save:

```
Parse\ParseObject Object
(
    [serverData:protected] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 9
            [image] => Parse\ParseFile Object
                (
                    [name:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 982621c6338150d34c345ee62baa3420_outlet-335936476.jpg
                    [url:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [data:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [mimeType:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                )

            [name] => Matzig 33'cl
        )

    [operationSet:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => Parse\Internal\SetOperation Object
                (
                    [value:Parse\Internal\SetOperation:private] => M?tzig 33'cl
                    [isAssociativeArray:Parse\Internal\SetOperation:private] => 
                )

        )

    [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 9
            [image] => Parse\ParseFile Object
                (
                    [name:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 982621c6338150d34c345ee62baa3420_outlet-335936476.jpg
                    [url:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [data:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [mimeType:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                )

            [name] => M?tzig 33'cl
        )

    [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 1
            [image] => 1
            [name] => 1
        )

    [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => products
    [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => vryoEYQqDe
    [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-03-03 09:08:43.217000
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

    [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-10 10:20:35.823000
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

    [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1
)
```

$object value after save!!

```
Parse\ParseObject Object
(
    [serverData:protected] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 9
            [image] => Parse\ParseFile Object
                (
                    [name:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 982621c6338150d34c345ee62baa3420_outlet-335936476.jpg
                    [url:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [data:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [mimeType:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                )

            [name] => M?tzig 33'cl
        )

    [operationSet:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 9
            [image] => Parse\ParseFile Object
                (
                    [name:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 982621c6338150d34c345ee62baa3420_outlet-335936476.jpg
                    [url:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [data:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                    [mimeType:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                )

            [name] => M?tzig 33'cl
        )

    [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 1
            [image] => 1
            [name] => 1
        )

    [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => products
    [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => vryoEYQqDe
    [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-03-03 09:08:43.217000
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

    [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-10 10:22:16.878000
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

    [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1
)
```

Here **M?tzig 33'cl** -> **?** == **'ä'**

Comment: What's the issue you are seeing? I.e. At data insert, display  page. Any error output?

Comment: thanks for the extra info, but how are you performing the update now without `Parse`? are you using MongoDB PHP driver/library ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar We are using Parse PHP SDK (Which is provided as open source as Parse is getting closed) and self-hosted MongoDB

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Could you confirm whether your database example above `prodcuts` is not a typo of `products` ? Also could you print the content of `$object` before `save()` and after `save()`.

Comment: @WanBachtiar - After your suggestion i tried printing the content of the $object and found that may be its not the problem of single quotes but UTF-8 characters.I have update the content above.